# Getting a time of deleted folder \ file

Tags: java

I am a newbie. A wanna to check for existing a folder or file in directory in past.

For better. Example, i may a directory C:\Users\Admin\AppData\ and i wanna to check of existing a directory Test in that path. That maybe be checket by:

```
File file = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\Test\\");
if(file.isDirectory()){
///...
} else { ////....}
```

But i wanna to check if that directory is deleted - when. Please help with code examples... be VERY and VERY thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to recover deleted files in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the File class, I recommend looking at the Files class - it is there to help you do many things.  For example, Files.createFile(...) will check to see if a file exists before creating.  You can then pass a positive result to FileWriter(...) for your work.

You can check for the presence of a file of folder, but not that it was deleted (e.g. checking a log file of past actions).  I recommend using the logic of "if not there then it never existed or was deleted".  Another option when working with files is to use parameters to always overwrite the file if that is what you want.

You are asking a question about the operating system.  What happens after a file or folder is deleted is unique to each operating system.  A notional recycle bin's awareness of a file or folder's original location was, and where that content may have been moved to is specific to an operating system (and usually isn't just moved into another folder).

Comment: okay, i wanna to ask. Do i may to check where directory was deleted? Becouse exists a program what check when some files was deleted. If you know how to do that - please say and with code if you may :-))

Comment: Quoting from this link, pretty much impossible: https://superuser.com/questions/530104/how-to-find-which-files-and-folders-were-deleted-recently-in-linux